# HttpClient HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved

Tags: java, httpclient, http-status-code-302

This code works for my simple testing login form. It uses POST to log in and then print all the information to the screen from logged view.  But it does not work on one specific website I have been creating this code all the way. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
package visualutopiabot;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {

                /* POST login */
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/login.asp");

                List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "nnnnick"));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pppassswww123"));

                httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);

                /* get content*/
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://website.com/index.asp");

                System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

                // Create a response handler
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(responseBody);
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");


            } finally {
                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
                // shut down the connection manager to ensure
                // immediate deallocation of all system resources
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer all along was that I was sending wrong POST queries. Instead of:

```
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "nnnnick"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pppassswww123"));
```

Had to write:

```
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "nnnnick"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "pppassswww123"));
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using [httpclient 3x](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)**

[GetMethod](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/GetMethod.html) has followRedirects flag set to true by default

You could try set set redirect to true explicitly for PostMethod

```
 PostMethod postMethod = ...;
 postMethod.setFollowRedirects(true)
```

**If you are using [httpcomponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)**

```
httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy());
httpost.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",true);
```

See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d4e1192 for further details

Answer (score 0):

302 means that the page has moved. You need to check the `Location` header on the response and retry your request on the url in that header.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP code 302 is one way to make a redirect. Your code probably correctly performs the login and then the server redirects it to another page. Either way, you should see the `Location:` header in the response and follow it.

Comment: Yeah location is set to the other. So let's say header shows new Location: YYY.com
I changed this part: 
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("YYY.com");

But it's still not working.

Comment: You shouldn't change the original login request, but add another request once you're redirected by the login reply.

Comment: Oh I think I found it. Forgot to change username and password to other fields that site use in here:
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "nnnnick"));
                nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pppassswww123"));

took so much time for this mistake.